# Possible to make a composite symbol?

Tags: symbols, esri, arcgis-js-api

When editing a vertex I would like to substitute the vertex symbol with SimpleMarkerSymbol and a TextSymbol but that appears to be impossible.  Any suggestions on how I could do this?  I want the appearance of dragging something like this (text + circle):

[image]

After taking some time to look at the API I've come to the conclusion it is impossible.  Here is my workaround:

```
editor.on("vertex-move", args => {
    let map = this.options.map;
    let g = <Graphic>args.vertexinfo.graphic;
    let startPoint = <Point>g.geometry;
    let tx = args.transform;
    let endPoint = map.toMap(map.toScreen(startPoint).offset(tx.dx, tx.dy));

    // draw a 'cursor' as a hack to render text over the active vertex
    if (!cursor) {
        cursor = new Graphic(endPoint, new TextSymbol({text: "foo"}));
        this.layer.add(cursor);
    } else {
        cursor.setGeometry(endPoint);
        cursor.draw();
    }
})
```

Comment: I hooked into the 'vertex-move' handler to create and update the location of a 'cursor' graphic.  It give the illusion of two symbols on a single graphic.

Comment: add code here...whatever u have tried so far,...

Comment: I've added my actual code but to get the effect I was originally looking for you'd want the vertextinfo.graphic to be the number and this "cursor" graphic to be the background because the dragging feature is always on top.

Comment: so basically u want to pass combined symbol here... [new TextSymbol({text: "foo"})].. let me try...

Answer (score 0):

Well, Achieve this seems **impossible** so far however ArcGIS JS API provides a new Application/platform where you can generate single symbol online for your applications.

We can simply create all kind of symbols(Provide by ESRI) online and it gives you on the fly code which you just need to paste in your application.

This will help us to try different type of suitable symbols for the applications.

Application URL: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/samples/playground/index.html

Hoping this will help you :)

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for.  This just creates the JSON for a single style.  I'm looking for a way of combining multiple styles into a single, composite style.  OpenLayers does this very well:
https://cdn.rawgit.com/ca0v/ol3-lab/v3.17.1/rawgit.html?run=labs/style-lab&debug=1

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `TextSymbol` to create a point with font type having numbers inside the circle. Here is one place where you can find such font. http://www.fontspace.com/the-fontsite/combinumerals

Wont be exactly as shown in the image but close enough. Also some limitation it wont work with IE9 or lower (this is as per esri documentation, as I am using halo to get the white border).

Here is the working Jsbin : http://jsbin.com/hayirebiga/edit?html,output use point of multipoint

PS: I have converted the ttf to otf and then added the font as base64, which is optional. I did it as I could not add the ttf or otf to jsbin.

Comment: My image was just an example.  I think there is no way of doing a composite.  You have to create multiple geometries, each with a single style, and keep them all in sync.  It's a terrible pain because each requires click handlers, duplicate attributes,etc.